# Is there a standard way of writing constructible numbers?

Tags: geometric-construction, symbolic-computation, algebraic-numbers

Every rational number can be represented by an irreducible fraction with a nonnegative denominator.

For expressions involving integers, the four basic operations of arithmetic and square roots, you can still factor out squares from square roots, and rationalize the denominators.

But, while exploring biquadratic equations and their solutions, i encountered two expressions for the same number, for instance :

$\frac{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{2}}}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{17}}}{2}$

Both have only one fraction line, no squares inside the square root symbols. So, is there a way to write such expressions with a unique canonical closed form ?

Comment: What is a "unique canonical closed form" exactly? Do you ask for a closed form of expressions $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}+\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}$, or of general double root expressions? Even $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ is not canonical., since both expressions represent the same number.

Comment: I mean a set of rules to apply on an expression representing a constructible number such that, applying these on two different expressions representing the same number should make them the same.